# Efeito CSS TRANSITION invertido

Tags: html, css, css-transições

Como faço para que essa barra de pesquisa em vez de ser aberta para direita ser aberta para esquerda?

```html
<style>

input.input_home {
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding-left: 50px;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: none;
  z-index: 3;
  transition: width 1s ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input:focus { 
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: width 1s ease-in;
}
button { 
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background:  url('lupa.png')  center no-repeat;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
/* esconde o LABEL "Buscar" */
label {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
  border: 0; 
}
</style>
<form action=" " method="post">
  <label for="busca">Buscar</label>
  <input class="input_home" type="search" id="busca" name="q">
  <button type="submit">OK</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu entendi vc quer que a barra cresça, mas que o btn OK fique na direita certo.

Da forma que vc construiu o Form a maneira que encontrei foi colocando um `margin-left` no `button` com um `transition` quando vc fizer o focus no `input`. Então ao mesmo tempo que vc faz o focus no `input` e faz o `transition` nele eu tb faço um `transition` no `button` que vem a seguir com

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vc vai reparar que eu usei dois `transition` no `button`, ou antes e outro depois do `:focus`, isso foi preciso para fazer o "ajuste fino" enquanto o elemento abre e fecha para que fica mais sincronizado, mas vc pode brincar com esses valores para ver o que mais te agrada.

Segue o código da imagem acima

```css
input.input_home {
 height: 50px;
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 padding-left: 50px;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: none;
 z-index: 3;
 transition: width 1s ease-out;
 cursor: pointer;
}

input:focus {
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 25px;
 width: 50%;
 z-index: -1;
 padding-right: 50px;

 transition: width 1s linear;
}

button {
 transition: margin-left 0s linear;
}

input:focus+button {
 margin-left: calc(50% - 65px);
 transition: margin-left 900ms linear;
 transition-delay: 100ms;
}

form {
 width: 50%;
}

button {
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 background: url('lupa.png') center no-repeat;
 /* background:  url('https://placecage.com/50/50')  center no-repeat; */
 border: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 2;
 cursor: pointer;
}

button:focus {
 outline: none;
}

/* esconde o LABEL "Buscar" */
label {
 position: absolute;
 width: 1px;
 height: 1px;
 padding: 0;
 margin: -1px;
 overflow: hidden;
 clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
 border: 0;
}
```

```html
<form action=" " method="post">
 <label for="busca">Buscar</label>
 <input class="input_home" type="search" id="busca" name="q">
 <button type="submit">OK</button>
</form>
```

Comment: O que eu gostaria brother é justamente o contrario, que o botão ficasse na direita e ao clicar nele a barra fosse pra esquerda

Comment: @Cairoodev se ela for pra esquerda vai ir para fora da tela...

Comment: ai basta eu colocar o botao do lado esquerdo também não? você consegue fazer isso?

Comment: ai o input e o btn vai ir para fora da tela, não vejo sentido nisso, acho que devo ter entendido algo errado, pois crescendo para esquerda não me parece correto. Tem como mostrar um exemplo ou explicar com um pouco mais de detalhe?

Comment: Isso que eu gostaria de saber se é possível fazer com esse código po. Basta imaginar esse efeito indo da direita para esquerda

Comment: @Cairoodev se é que eu entendi acho que daria sim, mas no caso o ideal seria ter um outro elemento ali por tras que nele teria essa borda cinza, e ele cresceria ao contrario. Vc teria que pensar em outra forma de montar essa estrutura de HTML e o CSS tb mudaria bastante.